# Editing master page only pushes changes to admin account

Tags: master-page

I have a SharePoint 2010 Enterprise farm on a VM and would like to edit the footer on each page on all sites. Currently, there is a custom div added to the master page, to supply extra text at the bottom of each page. Editing this, however, only displays the changes to our admin accounts, and all other users still see the old version of the footer. Is there a publishing step I am missing? I am new to admin and master page related activity so I'd be grateful for any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must save the master page, check it in as a major version, then approve the file in the Sharepoint site settings. Only then will it be available for all users.

Comment: That worked perfectly. Great concise and fast response. You rock!